# A limit and a coordinate trigonometric transformation of the interior points of a square into the interior points of a triangle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, limits, transformation, multivariable-calculus

The coordinate transformation (due to Beukers, Calabi and Kolk)

$$x=\frac{\sin u}{\cos v}$$

$$y=\frac{\sin v}{\cos u}$$

transforms the square domain $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $0\lt y\lt 1$ into the triangle domain $u,v>0,u+v<\pi /2$ (in *[Proofs from the BOOK](http://books.google.pt/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=proofs+from+the+book&source=bl&ots=swepaSdSxh&sig=j1gB1zxabJE8qxEgbFh1ig8RA3Q&hl=pt-PT&ei=Pnj2TKKcCZOKhQfb67yABg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by M. Aigner and G. Ziegler).

Since the invert transformation is

$$u=\arccos \sqrt{\dfrac{1-x^{2}}{1-x^{2}y^{2}}}$$

$$v=\arccos \sqrt{\dfrac{1-y^{2}}{1-x^{2}y^{2}}}$$

it is easy to see that three of the vertices (although not belonging to the domain) are transformed as follows:

$$(x,y)=(0,0)\mapsto (0,0)=(u,v),$$

$$(x,y)=(1,0)\mapsto (\pi /2,0)=(u,v),$$

$$(x,y)=(0,1)\mapsto (0,\pi /2)=(u,v).$$

**Question 1** - But how is the fourth vertex $(x,y)=(1,1)$ transformed? In the plot below of $\dfrac{1-x^{2}}{1-x^{2}y^{2}}$ seems that the following limit does not exist

$$\underset{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,1)}{\lim }\sqrt{\dfrac{1-x^{2}}{1-x^{2}y^{2}}}.$$

[image]

**Question 2** - As a second question I would like to know how can one "discover" a
transformation of a square into a triangle such as this. *Is there any systematic study of this kind of transformations?*

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: You are right. I've corrected to vertices, that was what I meant. It was an error. @Rasmus: it should read "how is the forth vertex (x,y)=(1,1) transformed".

Comment: @Rasmus: That's right. This transformation is presented in the context of evaluating  a non trivial double integral over the interior of the square defined above. The transformed integral is a simple double integral over the interior of the triangle I mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1: Setting $u=\pi/2-v$ in your first set of formulas gives $(x,y)=(1,1)$, so that point corresponds to the whole hypotenuse $u+v=\pi/2$.

Question 2: I have no idea. (Luck? Inspiration? Trial and error?)

Comment: It is amazing that the square vertex $(x,y)=(1,1)$ "corresponds to the whole hypotenuse $u+v=\pi/2$". Hence the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Regarding question 2, maybe the following paper can give an idea: https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3602