# Jacobian physical meaning

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Jacobian Matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/what-is-jacobian-matrix)

Is there any physical intuition for the Jacobian?

I understand that it is the matrix of partial derivatives and how to construct it. What I want to know is

- what's the use of it? Application wise
- is there a nice intuitive explanation for it? I mean regarding its significance and otherwise

Comment: There is a geometric intuition: this is how a small volume changes after a coordinate change.

Comment: What about it's application? Where is it used?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_matrix) offers useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jacobian is the matrix that represents the linear transformation that takes a small change in the *input* of a function to the corresponding small change in *output*:

For $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, a fixed $x \in \mathbb R^n$, we have
$$f(x+h) = f(x) + J(x)h + o(|h|) \qquad\text{for }h\in\mathbb R^m, h\to 0$$
provided that the various partial derivatives exist and behave sufficiently nicely.

In this way the Jacobian is the direct analogue of the derivative in ordinary real analysis.