# Find a family of random variables $X$, with density $f$, such that $X$ and $Y=f(X)$ have the same distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have to demonstrate the following Probability/Statistics result:

"Find a family of random variables $X$, having pdf $f$, such that $X$ and $Y=f(X)$ have the same distribution."

I have tried to find a proof to this result and I found out that, in the case of pdf $f$ strictly increasing, the result is true if $f$ is the identity function.

I have to find a characterization even in the following 2 cases:

1. $f$ strictly decreasing;
2. $f$ stictly increseasing for $x\leq m$ and stricly decreasing for $x \geq m$ (where $m$ is the mode of the distribution).

Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Comment: Just a remark. The identity function is not a valid PDF, since it can take negative values and doesn't integrate to $1$.
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in[0,\sqrt{2}] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
would do though.

Comment: @Leander Tilsted Kristensen Thanks for the remark. I already realized that the identity function was not a valid pdf and I had to put some restrictions to the domain in order to have the correct properties for the pdf. Thanks for having told me that!

Comment: Interesting problem! I'll spend more time on it tomorrow. In the meantime, one potential way to move forward is to note that for r.v. $X$ with cdf $F_X(x)$, $F_X(X) \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, that is, plugging any r.v. into its own cdf results in a standard uniform distribution.

Comment: @Jack Gallagher Thanks for your interesting comment!

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer contained a fatal flaw in logic, caused by not taking the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian in the change of variables theorem. The following is a more precise answer.

---

Let $X$ have pdf $f_X(x)$, $Y$ have pdf $f_Y(y)$, and $Y=g(X)$.

By the change of variables theorem (sketches of the proof of which can be found in a previous MSE post [Intuitive proof of multivariable changing of variables formula (jacobian) without using mapping and/or measure theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267267/intuitive-proof-of-multivariable-changing-of-variables-formula-jacobian-withou), we have

$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))\cdot \left| D_y g^{-1}(y) \right| $

Now, for this question, we are interested in the case where $f_X=f_Y=g$. Call this $f$.

Then the change of variables equation becomes

$f(y)=f\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)\cdot\left|D_y f^{-1}(y) \right|$

and we must now assume $f$ is monotonic since otherwise $f^{-1}$ does not exist as a function. Applying the chain rule, we obtain:

$f(y)=f\left(f^{-1}(y)\right) \cdot \left| \frac{1}{(D_y f) \left( f^{-1}(y) \right) } \right| $

Due to monotonicity,

$f(y)=y \cdot \left| \frac{1}{(D_yf)\left( f^{-1}(y) \right) } \right| $

It can easily be shown that $f(y)=ay^n$, $n=\pm1$, $a\geq0$ are sufficient to fulfill this criterion, but I'm not sure how to prove they are necessary.

Wikipedia's article on [Probability density functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) gives an interesting formula I hadn't seen in my prob theory courses, which deals with nonmonotonic transformation functions:

$$f_Y(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n(y)}\left|D_y g_k^{-1}(y)\right|\cdot f_X(g_k^{-1}(y))$$

where $n(y)$ is the number of $x$ such that $g(x)=y$ (essentially this is just combining the strictly increasing and strictly decreasing cases into one function). In your third case, where the density is unimodal, $n=2$ and the formula becomes:

$f(y)=\left|D_yf_1^{-1}(y)\right|\cdot f\left(f_1^{-1}(y)\right)+\left|D_yf_2^{-1}(y)\right|\cdot f\left(f_2^{-1}(y)\right)$

where $f_1, f_2$ are respectively your strictly increasing and strictly decreasing densities on their proper intervals (denoted here with indicator functions $I$):

$f_1(y)=p\frac{y-\mathcal{l}}{m-\mathcal{l}}I_{(\mathcal{l}, m]}(y)$

$f_2(y)=p\frac{1}{y-m+1}I_{(m, n]}(y)$

where $0<\mathcal{l}<m<n<\infty$ and $p=\frac{1}{\frac{m-\mathcal{l}}{2}+\ln{(n-m+1)}}$.

Since

$\left|D_yf_1^{-1}(y)\right|=\left|\frac{m-\mathcal{l}}{p}\right|=\frac{m-\mathcal{l}}{p}$ and

$\left|D_yf_2^{-1}(y)\right|=\left|-\frac{p}{y^2}\right|=\frac{p}{y^2}$

Our density becomes

$f(y)=(y-\mathcal{l})I_{(\mathcal{l}, m]}(y)+\frac{p^2}{y^2(y-m+1)}I_{(m, n]}(y)$

Comment: I worked a lot on this result in order to find a characterization for the cases of strictly decreasing and the other one in the last days, but I didn't find any class of valid functions that can work. Your answer confirms what I thought: there's not a criteria for the other 2 cases. Thanks, @Jack Gallagher!

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $f$ must satisfy $f(f(x))=x$ ??. I mean if we transform a random variable $X$ with PDF $f$ by a strictly monotone differentiable function $g$, we would get 
$$f_{g(X)}(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) | \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) |,$$
so it seems like $f$ should rather satisfy
$$f(y) = f(f^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy} f^{-1}(y)| = y|\frac{d}{dy} f^{-1}(y)|$$

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I initially had a proof using that formula and got $f(x) = x$ as the only solution. But you're absolutely right that that first step of mine seems like it's on quite shaky ground. I'll review my argument

Comment: Ah, I found my error in that first proof--I had written the transformation formula as $f_Y(y)=f_X(y) D_y f^{-1}(x)$, as I read the $|\cdot|$ in my notes (we covered the more general 2D case in my Intro Prob class 3 years ago) as just taking the determinant of the Jacobian, not also taking the absolute value. That explains but certainly doesn't excuse the faulty logic I used in reducing met.91's problem to f(f(x))=f(x).

Comment: @met.91 I've updated my answer. Barring any errors, I believe I found such an $f$ for the unimodal case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to submit another result that I've just found out.

Considering $f$ strictly decreasing, I know (from previous demonstrated results) that the following equation is valid:

$$1-F\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)=F(y)$$

where we know that $y=f(x)$ so that the equation becomes

$$ 1 - F(x)=F\big(f(x)\big)$$

where $F$ is the CDF and $f$ is the PDF of the random variable $X$, such that

$$1-F(x)=F\big(F'(x)\big)\text.$$

The solution is $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+a^{2}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\text.$$

Derivating the expression of $F(x)$ we obtain that
$$ f(x)=\frac{a^{2}}{x}\text.$$

If we consider the following

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a^{2}}{x}, \, &{x \in \left[1, e^{\frac{1}{a^{2}}}\right] } \\
0, \, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Can it be considered as a valid PDF?

1. $f(x)$ is $\geq 0$, for $x \in \left[1, e^{\frac{1}{a^{2}}}\right] $;
2. the integral of $f(x)$ between $1$ and $e^{\frac{1}{a^{2}}}$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: You are correct and I am wrong. My logic was faulty due to missing an absolute value sign in the transformation. I'll edit my answer to fix its faulty logic over the coming days.

Comment: This is nice, and almost correct. The problem is that if 
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{a^2}{x} &, x \in [1,e^{1/a^2}] \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
, then $Y=f_X(X)$ has PDF
$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{a^2}{y} &, y \in [a^2e^{-1/a^2},a^2] \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise} \end{cases},$$
so the PDF's are not defined on the same interval.

Comment: Setting $a=1$ i found that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} &, x \in [e^{-1/2},e^{1/2}] \\ 0 &,\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
does the trick, since $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ maps the interval $[e^{-1/2},e^{1/2}]$ into itself.

Comment: @Leander Tilsted Kristensen Thanks for your interesting comments. Very nice observations! This problem that I'm trying to solve and demonstrate is soooo interesting, but so tough at the same time.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen If we consider $$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a^{2}}{x}, \, &{x \in \Bigr[e^{\frac{-1}{2a^{2}}}, e^{\frac{1}{2a^{2}}}\Bigl] } \\
0, \, &{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ 

does this function generalize your $f(x)$? This should work as a valid PDF and the interval $\Bigr[e^{\frac{-1}{2a^{2}}}, e^{\frac{1}{2a^{2}}}\Bigl]$ should go, through $f(x)$, to itself. 
Is this right?

Comment: @met.91 not quite, but close. I believe the general formula should be
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{a^2}{x} &, x \in [ae^{\frac{-1}{2a^2}},ae^{\frac{1}{2a^2}}] \\
0 &,\text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
I found this interval by noticing that $x\mapsto a^2/x$ maps an interval $[b,c]$ to $[\frac{a^2}{c},\frac{a^2}{b}]$. So we need $b = \frac{a^2}{c}$ and $c=\frac{a^2}{b}$ or equavalently $a^2 = bc$. And also, since the integral must be $1$ we must have $\log(\frac{c}{b}) = \frac{1}{a^2}$.

Comment: @Leander Tilsted Kristensen That interval should be correct. If we use those values and we calculate the limits of $F(x)$ (the CDF of the random variable $X$), the limit to $a e^{\frac{-1}{2a^{2}}}$ is $0$ and the one to $a e^{\frac{1}{2a^{2}}}$ goes to $1$ and $F(x)$ should be a correct CDF. Is this right?