# Derive p.d.f of Functions of Random Variables

Tags: calculus, probability

In Degroot: Probability and Statistics, there's a general formula for functions of Random Variables.

Suppose: X1, X2... Xn have a joint continuous p.d.f f(.), and there're one-to-one correspondence functions Y1 = r1(X1, ... Xn), Y2 = r2(X1, ... Xn), ... Yn = rn(X1, ... Xn), as well as the inverse X1 = s1(Y1,...Yn), Y2 = s2(Y1,...Yn),...,Yn = sn(Y1,...Yn). Assume  si(.) has partial derivatives, so there's Jacobian determinant |J| of si(.).

Assume vector X is not 0 in area D, and the correspondence area is T for vector Y. Then, the joint p.d.f of Y is

g(y1, y2,...,yn) = f(s1, s2, ... sn) * |J| for(y1, y2,...,yn) in T; 0, otherwise.

The author didn't give derivation of this formula. How to derive it rirugously? (one can use change of variable formula in multi-calculus directly without proof)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [this question on an intuitive proof for this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267267/intuitive-proof-of-multivariable-changing-of-variables-formula-jacobian-withou)

Comment: @ CommunityBot give a proof of the formula.

Comment: @GrahamKemp it's a derive of variable changing for multi-variable calculus, not probability. But it helps to see why there's a Jacobian determiant.