# How bad is the error in the volume of a transformed region, when the transformation is approximated as linear?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration, change-of-variable

For context, I'm trying to prove the change of variables theorem for Riemann integrals. I need to know how a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $f$ changes the volume of a region. Here's what I know already:

- The Riemann integral can be equivalently defined using partitions into arbitrary compact Jordan-measurable sets (CJM sets), instead of (hyper)rectangles. (That is, after we've defined Jordan measure using rectangles.)
- A $C^1$ diffeomorphism, applied to a CJM set, is a CJM set. (Proposition 10.5.6 in [Jiří Lebl's notes](https://math.okstate.edu/people/lebl/osu4153-s16/))
- A linear transformation changes volume by the absolute value of its determinant.
- Given that $f$ is continuously differentiable, there is a continuous function $h$ of two variables such that $$f(x) = f(y) + f'(y)\, (x - y) + h(x, y)\, \lVert x - y\rVert,\qquad h(y, y) = 0,$$ for all $x$ and $y$. (Here $f'(y)$ is a matrix, and all the other things are vectors, except of course $\lVert x-y\rVert$.)

Denote the volume of a region $R$ as $V(R) = \int\, [x \in R]\, dx$, using Iverson brackets: $[\text{true}]=1,\; [\text{false}]=0$.

What I want is a bound on the difference $V(f(R)) - |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$, where $y$ is some point in $R$, and $R$ is some CJM subset of a fixed CJM set. The region $R$ could be a small rectangle, to simplify things. Specifically, for any $\varepsilon>0$, I want some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $R$ with diameter smaller than $\delta$, and for all $y \in R$, that volume difference is smaller than $\varepsilon\, V(R)$.

Comment: See proposition 3.1.14 on page 99 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: Thanks, though it doesn't answer the question. Relation 3.1.49 needs some more explanation/justification.

Comment: @mr_e_man While it's true that the author did not fully justify 3.1.49, it is a relatively straightforward exercise to show that 3.1.49 can be achieved. I'll post a proof eventually.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\assign}{:=}
\newcommand{\nosymbol}{}
\newcommand{\of}{:}
\newcommand{\tmop}[1]{{\operatorname{#1}}}$$

In 3.1.49 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf, the author claims that given $\varepsilon > 0$, if $\delta > 0$ is
small enough and $\tmop{maxsize} (\mathcal{P}) \leq \delta$, then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \eta_{\alpha} + (1 + \varepsilon) H_{\alpha} & \supset & G (R_{\alpha}) 
  \text{ for all } R_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{P},
\end{eqnarray*}
that is,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  G (\xi_{\alpha}) + (1 + \varepsilon) D G (\xi_{\alpha})  \tilde{R}_{\alpha}
  & \supset & G (R_{\alpha})  \text{ for all } R_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{P}.
\end{eqnarray*}
We can show this by brute force. By properties of the Riemann integral, we may
assume each $R_{\alpha}$ is a cube $R_{\alpha} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \of | x
- \xi_{\alpha} |_{\infty} \leq \delta_{\alpha} \}$. Fix $R_{\alpha} \in
\mathcal{P}$. Let $\xi_{\alpha} + y \in R_{\alpha}$ (i.e. $y \in
\tilde{R}_{\alpha}$). Then we want to find $v$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  G (\xi_{\alpha} + y) & = & G (\xi_{\alpha}) + D G (\xi_{\alpha}) v.
\end{eqnarray*}
By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  G (\xi_{\alpha} + y) & = & G (\xi_{\alpha}) + D G (\xi_{\alpha}) y + \Phi
  (\xi_{\alpha}, y) y,\\
  \Phi (\xi, y) & = & \int_0^1 (D G (\xi + ty) - D G (\xi)) d t.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we want
\begin{eqnarray*}
  G (\xi_{\alpha}) + D G (\xi_{\alpha}) y + \Phi (\xi_{\alpha}, y) y & = & G
  (\xi_{\alpha}) + D G (\xi_{\alpha}) v.
\end{eqnarray*}
Performing algebra yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
  v & = & y + D G (\xi_{\alpha})^{- 1} \Phi (\xi_{\alpha}, y) y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let us use $\tmop{maxsize} (\mathcal{P}) \assign \max_{R_{\alpha} \in
\mathcal{P}} \delta_{\alpha}$. Suppose $\tmop{maxsize} (\mathcal{P}) =
\delta$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  {| v |_{\infty}}_{\nosymbol} & \leq & (1 + \| D G (\xi_{\alpha})^{- 1} \Phi
  (\xi_{\alpha}, y) \|)  | y |_{\infty}\\
  & \leq & (1 + \sup_{\xi \in R, | x | \leq \delta} \| D G (\xi)^{- 1} \Phi
  (\xi, x) \|)  | y |_{\infty}\\
  & \assign & (1 + q (\delta))  | y |_{\infty}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $v \in (1 + q (\delta))  \tilde{R}_{\alpha}$. Since $y$ was arbitrary,
$$ G (R_{\alpha}) \subset G (\xi_{\alpha}) + D G (\xi_{\alpha}) (1 + q
   (\delta))  \tilde{R}_{\alpha} = G (\xi_{\alpha}) + (1 + q (\delta)) D G
   (\xi_{\alpha})  \tilde{R}_{\alpha} . $$
We now need to show that $q (\delta) = \sup_{\xi \in R, \| x \| \leq \delta}
\| D G (\xi)^{- 1} \Phi (\xi, x) \| \rightarrow 0$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$.
Note that since $R \subset \mathcal{O}$ can be as small as we like, we can
ensure there exists $r > 0$ such that $\Phi \of R \times \overline{B_r (0)}
\rightarrow M (n \times n, \mathbb{R})$ is well defined (we just need $\{ x
\of d (x, R) \leq r \} \subset \mathcal{O}$). Then note that $\Phi$ is
continuous, and $\Phi (\xi, 0) = 0$. Since $\Phi$ is continuous on a compact
set, $\Phi$ is uniformly continuous, so $q (\delta) = \sup_{x \in R, \| x \|
\leq \delta}  (\Phi (\xi, x) - \Phi (\xi, 0)) \rightarrow 0$ as $\delta
\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I haven't read this yet, but the partition $\mathcal P$ and the subscripts $\alpha$ are irrelevant distractions (like the integrand function). -- Also, can you get the reverse containment, $$G(R_\alpha)\supset\eta_\alpha+(1-\varepsilon)H_\alpha\quad?$$

Comment: When you write $|x|_\infty\leq\delta_\alpha$, you're assuming that $\overset\sim R_\alpha$ is a cube, not a general rectangle? And what is $\overset\sim{\mathcal O}$ ?

Comment: @mr_e_man You are right, it is more convenient to assume $\tilde{R}_{\alpha}$ is a cube. This is fine since you get the same upper and lower integrals when considering partitions consisting of cubes only as opposed to partitions consisting of arbitrary rectangles. $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$ was a typo, it is supposed to be $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @mr_e_man The reverse containment is more subtle, and is not needed for the proof of the change of variables theorem for a $C^1$ diffeomorphism because $G^{-1}$ is also a $C^1$ diffeomorphism in this case. It appears to require degree theory to prove. See page 91 of "Measure Theory and Integration" by Michael Taylor for a proof of the reverse containment.

Comment: @mr_e_man If you want to get rid of all the distractions, measure theory is the way to go. (7.41) on page 90 of "Measure Theory and Integration" by Michael Taylor of captures the essence of what we really need to prove.

Comment: I thought of using the $\infty$ norm before I posted the question, but it didn't seem to work, because both the cube's curved image and its linear approximation are not cubes/rectangles. You solved this by applying the inverse linear transformation, so that the curved image could be compared to cubes. It's a simple idea, but I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that the one-way inequality is sufficient for the change of variables theorem, but we have to break the integrand into positive and negative parts. It is ugly. And the OP asks for a two-way inequality (though perhaps I should have used the word "absolute" somewhere to make that explicit). I'm working on my own answer, to see if I can get a reversed inequality, also generalizing to non-cubes.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yeah you just write the integrand $h$ as $h = h^+ - h^{-}$, so the change of variables theorem for nonnegative integrands implies the general case. Once you have the change of variables theorem, you can just use $$V(f(R)) = \int_{f(R)}1\,dx = \int_{R}|\det Df(y)|\,dy$$ to obtain $$V(f(R)) - |\det Df(z)|V(R) = \int_{R}(|\det Df(y)| - |\det Df(z)|)\,dy,$$ and that is easily bounded. The point is that the reverse containment $G(R_a) \supset \eta_{\alpha} + (1 - \varepsilon)H_{\alpha}$ for some $\varepsilon$ is true, but more subtle than the change of variables theorem.

Comment: Any comments on the case where $f$ is $C^1$ but not invertible?

Comment: If $f$ is $C^1$ on an open set $O$, then for every $x_0 \in O$, $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{V(f(Q_{\varepsilon}(x_0)))}{V(Q_{\varepsilon}(x_0))} = |\det Df(x_0)|,$$ where $Q_{\varepsilon}(0) = \{x : |x|_{\infty} < \varepsilon\}$. When $|\det Df(x_0)| \neq 0$, then by the inverse function theorem, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ on which $f$ is a diffeomorphism, so the usual change of variables applies. For the case $|\det Df(x_0)| = 0$, a direct estimate similar to the above proof shows the claim.

Answer (score 0):

First we'll prove an upper bound for cubes: $V(f(R)) \leq (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$. We'll use the max norm, $\lVert v\rVert=\max\{|v_k|:1\leq k\leq n\}$ (where $n$ is the dimension), so $R=\{x:\lVert x-y\rVert\leq r\}$ is a cube with edge length $2r$. (The diameter is $2r$ according to this norm, though it would be $2r\sqrt n$ according to the Euclidean norm.)

According to the fourth bullet in the OP,

$$f'(y)^{-1} (f(x) - f(y))\;  =\;  x - y + f'(y)^{-1} h(x,y) \lVert x - y\rVert,$$

which implies, by the triangle inequality,

$$\lVert f'(y)^{-1} (f(x) - f(y))\rVert\;  \leq\;  \lVert x - y\rVert\, \big(1 + \lVert f'(y)^{-1} h(x,y)\rVert\big).$$

Since both $f'^{-1}$ and $h$ are continuous on a compact set and $h(y,y)=0$, given $0<\varepsilon'\leq1$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that (for all $x$ and $y$, uniformly) if $\lVert x-y\rVert\leq\delta$ then $\lVert f'(y)^{-1} h(x,y)\rVert\leq\varepsilon'$. Now, if the cube $R$ has diameter $2r\leq2\delta$, and $y$ is its centre and $x$ is any other point in it (which is to say that $\lVert x-y\rVert\leq r\leq\delta$), then

$$\lVert f'(y)^{-1} (f(x) - f(y))\rVert\;  \leq\;  \lVert x - y\rVert\, \big(1 + \varepsilon'\big)$$
$$\leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon') r$$
$$f'(y)^{-1} (f(x) - f(y))\;  \in\;  (1 + \varepsilon') (R - y)$$
$$f(x) - f(y)\;  \in\;  (1 + \varepsilon')\, f'(y) (R - y).$$

Since $f(x) - f(y)$ is an arbitrary point in $f(R) - f(y)$, this shows that

$$f(R) - f(y)\;  \subset\;  (1 + \varepsilon')\, f'(y) (R - y).$$

As translations don't change volume, and we know how linear transformations change volume, we get

$$V(f(R))\;  \leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon')^n\, |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$$
$$=\;  \left(1 + \varepsilon' \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 + \varepsilon')^k\right) |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$$
$$\leq\;  \left(1 + \varepsilon' \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k\right) |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$$
$$\leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon'\, 2^n)\, |\det f'(y)|\, V(R).$$

Thus, given any $\varepsilon>0$, we can define $\varepsilon'=\min\{1,\, \varepsilon/2^n\}$ and go through the above process to get $\delta$. For any cube $R$ with any centre $y$ and diameter less than $2\delta$, we have $V(f(R)) \leq (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(y)|\, V(R)$, as claimed.

---

Next we'll extend that upper bound to CJM sets. Denote such a set as $S$, with $z \in S$. (The letters $R$ and $y$ remain for cubes and their centres.) We want to show $V(f(S)) \leq (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(z)|\, V(S)$ for small enough $S$.

Find upper and lower bounds $0<L\leq|\det f'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$.

Given any $\varepsilon'>0$, get $\delta'>0$ from the previous section, and get $\delta''>0$ from the uniform continuity of $|\det f'(x)|$, and set $\delta=\min\{\delta',\delta''\}$. Suppose $S$ has diameter less than $\delta$, so it's contained in a cube $R$ with centre $z$ and diameter less than $2\delta$. As $S$ is Jordan-measurable, for any $\varepsilon''>0$ there is a cubic partition of $R$ such that

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} R_i\;  \subset\;  S\;  \subset\;  \bigcup_{i\in I\cup J} R_i\;  \subset\;  R,\qquad  \sum_{i\in J} V(R_i) \leq \varepsilon''.$$

The index set $I$ is for the interior of $S$, and $J$ for the boundary of $S$. Noting that the cubes are essentially disjoint, i.e. they intersect only on their boundaries which have measure zero, and diffeomorphisms preserve this property, we also have

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} f(R_i)\;  \subset\;  f(S)\;  \subset\;  \bigcup_{i\in I\cup J} f(R_i),$$
$$\bigcup_{i\in I} f'(z)(R_i)\;  \subset\;  f'(z)(S)\;  \subset\;  \bigcup_{i\in I\cup J} f'(z)(R_i),$$
$$\sum_{i\in I} V(R_i)\;  \leq\;  V(S)\;  \leq\;  \sum_{i\in I\cup J} V(R_i),$$
$$\sum_{i\in I} V(f(R_i))\;  \leq\;  V(f(S))\;  \leq\;  \sum_{i\in I\cup J} V(f(R_i)).$$

These cubes of course (being smaller than $R$) have diameter less than $2\delta$. Hence,

$$V(f(S))\;  \leq\;  \sum_{i\in I\cup J} V(f(R_i))$$
$$\leq\;  \sum_{i\in I\cup J} (1 + \varepsilon')\, |\det f'(y_i)|\, V(R_i)$$
$$\leq\;  \sum_{i\in I\cup J} (1 + \varepsilon')\, \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'\big)\, V(R_i)$$
$$=\;  (1 + \varepsilon')\, \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'\big)\, \left(\sum_{i\in I} V(R_i) + \sum_{i\in J} V(R_i)\right)$$
$$\leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon')\, \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'\big)\, \big(V(S) + \varepsilon''\big),$$

and since $\varepsilon''>0$ was arbitrary,

$$V(f(S))\;  \leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon')\, \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'\big)\, V(S)$$
$$=\;  \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon' + \varepsilon'^2\big)\, V(S)$$
$$\leq\;  \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon'(M + 1 + \varepsilon')\big)\, V(S).$$

Now, given any $\varepsilon>0$, we can define $\varepsilon'=\min\{1,\, \varepsilon L/(M+2)\}$ and go through the above process to get $\delta$. For any CJM set $S$ with diameter less than $\delta$, and any $z \in S$, we have

$$V(f(S))\;  \leq\;  \big(|\det f'(z)| + \varepsilon L\big)\, V(S)$$
$$\leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(z)|\, V(S)$$

as claimed. Note that we could just as well use the bound $V(f(S)) \leq |\det f'(z)|\, V(S) + \varepsilon\, V(S)$ as in the OP, due to the determinant bounds $L$ and $M$.

---

Lastly we'll get a lower bound on the volume, by considering the inverse diffeomorphism $g=f^{-1}$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, get $\delta'>0$ from the previous section applied to $g$ instead of $f$. Plug this $\delta'$ into the uniform continuity of $f$ to get $\delta>0$. Suppose $R \ni y$ is a CJM set with diameter less than $\delta$, so $S=f(R) \ni z=f(y)$ is a CJM set with diameter less than $\delta'$. Then

$$V(g(S))\;  \leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det g'(z)|\, V(S),$$

that is,

$$V(R)\;  \leq\;  (1 + \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(y)^{-1}|\, V(f(R))$$
$$\leq\;  \frac1{1 - \varepsilon}\, |\det f'(y)^{-1}|\, V(f(R)).$$

(We can assume $\varepsilon<1$.) This gives us the desired result

$$V(f(R))\;  \geq\;  (1 - \varepsilon)\, |\det f'(y)|\, V(R).$$

Again, we could just as well use the form in the OP, $V(f(R)) \geq |\det f'(y)|\, V(R) - \varepsilon\, V(R)$, due to the determinant bounds.