# relationship of gamma and beta functions

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I was reading a article on proving the relationship between gamma and beta functions  but there are some things I don't understand.

[image]

Then the variables are changed as
 [image]

Then they have obtained
[image]

this.But I don't understand $dv$is obtained.(when changing variables v = s+t has to be differentiated) .Since v include both s and t how is it differentiated and with respect to what.Also how does v change from 0 to v

Comment: Hello clarkson, have you had experience with double integrals and changes of coordinates before? What you are looking for is called the Jacobian and information can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/what-is-jacobian-matrix). The first link should teach you how to use it and the second link should explain what it is.

Comment: I don't know Jacobian.I'll read those links.Is there any other method to prove this gamma beta relationship without having to use Jacobian

Comment: I understand the Jacobian part.But still I don't understand how v vary from 0 to v

Comment: Be sure to note that it's $u$ that varies from $0$ to $v$. In my mind I see that $u = s$ and that, because $v$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ and $u$ goes to $v$, you will cover all values of $s$ from $0$ to $\infty$. Likewise, $t$ must also go to $\infty$ because $v$ does.