# Chain rule for partial derivatives intuition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Can somebody give me an intuitive explanation for the below equations. I'm not sure how they come about and how they can be perceived logically.

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} $$

Comment: Presumably $z = f$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, my apologies.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't think it's correct to say that $z = f$ ; rather, $z(s,t) = f(x(s,t),y(s,t))$.  $f$ and $z$ aren't the same function.  People often aren't careful to distinguish $z$ and $f$ in this context but I find that to be confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that $z = f(x,y)$ and $x,y$ are functions of $s$. The partial derivatives of $z$ given a first-order approximation for $z$:
$$ f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y) \approx f(x,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \Delta y. $$
The error in this approximation should be "small", say $o(\Delta x+\Delta y)$ (if you don't know what this means, it's not important). Similarly,
$$
x(s+\Delta s) \approx x(s) + \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s, \quad
y(s+\Delta s) \approx y(s) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s.
$$
Finally, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ satisfies
$$
f(x(s+\Delta s),y(s+\Delta s)) \approx f(x(s),y(s)) + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s.
$$
We can now prove the formula:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x(s+\Delta s),y(s+\Delta s)) &\approx
f(x(s) + \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s, y(s) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s) \\ &\approx
f(x(s),y(s)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s) \Delta s.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

According to the chain rule $$(g \circ f)'(x_0) = g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)$$

The matrix of the composition of two linear funtions is the product of their respective matrices. Hence the matrix  $(g \circ f)'(x_0)$ of $d_{x_0}(g \circ f)$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \\\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix} $$

To illustrate suppose $f$ and $g$ are given by

$$w = g(x,y,z), \ \ x = f_1 (s,t), \ \ y = f_2(s,t), \ \ z = f_3(s,t) $$

Then by the chain rule

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial w}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix} $$

Which yields

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial w}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\\\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} &=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \end{align}$$

*Note: Take a close look to [transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) and [Jacobian Matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/what-is-jacobian-matrix) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHBkQW_XuA4) may also help.

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that the $\partial f$ in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is different from (and independent of) the $\partial f$ in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Think of the former $\partial f$ as a change in $f$ due to a change in $x$ and the latter as a change in $f$ due to a change in $y$. Because a change in $s$ causes both a change in $y$ and a change in $x$, we need to add the change in $f$ due to a change in $x$ (which in turn was caused by a change in $s$) to the change in $f$ due to a change in $y$ (which in turn was caused by a change in $s$). If you need more clarification, re-read my first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
z(s + \Delta s, t) &= f(x(s + \Delta s, t),y(s + \Delta s, t)) \\& \approx 
f \left(x(s,t) + \frac{\partial x(s,t)}{\partial s} \Delta s,y(s,t) + \frac{\partial y(s,t)}{\partial s} \Delta s \right) \\
\tag{$\spadesuit$}&\approx f(x(s,t),y(s,t)) + \frac{\partial f(x(s,t),y(s,t))}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x(s,t)}{\partial s} \Delta s
\\& \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad+ \frac{\partial f(x(s,t),y(s,t))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(s,t)}{\partial s} \Delta s.
\end{align}

Comparing this with
\begin{equation}
z(s + \Delta s, t) \approx z(s,t) + \frac{\partial z(s,t)}{\partial s} \Delta s
\end{equation}
we discover that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z(s,t)}{\partial s} = 
\frac{\partial f(x(s,t),y(s,t))}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x(s,t)}{\partial s} 
+ \frac{\partial f(x(s,t),y(s,t))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(s,t)}{\partial s} .
\end{equation}

The key step is in line ($\spadesuit$), where we use the approximation
\begin{equation}
f(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y)
\approx f(x,y) + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \Delta x
+ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}{\Delta y}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Why does the approximation $\spadesuit$ hold?