# Why is the definition of derivative what it is?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition, intuition

In our lectures, we've been taught the following:

> We say that $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $X$,iff there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$\epsilon (H)=\frac{f(X+H)-f(X)-\alpha\cdot H}{\|H\|}\to0$$ as $\|H\|\to0$ and the derivative is $\alpha$

But I can't understand why this should work? What is the intuition behind setting up $\epsilon(H)$ like this? Why the dot product ($\alpha\cdot H$)? What does $\alpha$ represent physically on the curve?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: The $\alpha$ is the linear transformation that best approximates $f$ in a small enough region. See Wikipedia page on [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative).

Comment: Note there's no “curve” when $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.  The graph of $f$ is a three-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  Intuitive notions of derivative aren't as reliable in higher dimensions.

Comment: Although many mathematical concepts originated from physics, many lose their physical meaning when they become abstract and general. There are many instances when you cannot interpret a mathematical concept physically.

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127350/40119) attempts to shed some light on the definition of the derivative when $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$.

Comment: @edm - perhaps, but this is not one of them. As artic tern has noted, $\alpha$ is the gradient of $f$. It points in the direction in which $f$ is increasing fastest, and its magnitude is the rate of increase of $f$ in that direction. More generally, any concept that truly deserves the name "derivative" will have a strong geometric (i.e. "physical") interpretation, as the point of a derivative is to give a best linear approximation of a mapping, which is a geometric concept.

Answer (score 4):

Say $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a scalar function.

The **directional derivative** of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$ is

$$ D_{\mathbf{v}}f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}. $$

If we interpret $f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})$ as a function of $h$ with $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}$ fixed, this is

$$\begin{array}{l} \displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v}) &= \displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial (x_1+hv_1)}{\partial h}+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial(x_n+hv_n)}{\partial h} \\[5pt] & \displaystyle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}v_1+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}v_n  \end{array} $$

at $h=0$ (so all the partials $\partial f/\partial x_i$ are evaluated at $\mathbf{x}$) by the multivariable chain rule.

This is just the dot product $D_{\mathbf{v}}f(\mathbf{x})=\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\cdot \mathbf{v}$ where $\nabla f$ is the **gradient**.

Rearranging, this may be written as

$$ \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})-\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\cdot(h\mathbf{v})}{h}\to0 \quad \textrm{as }h\to0. $$

With the substitution $\mathbf{h}=h\mathbf{v}$ this becomes

$$\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})-\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{h}}{\|\mathbf{h}\|}\to0 \quad \textrm{as }\|\mathbf{h}\|\to0. $$

The derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ in this case is a vector $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}^n$ depending on $\mathbf{x}$.

More generally one can do the same thing to vector functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, in which case a linear function $Df:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ will be applied to $\mathbf{h}$ instead of a dot product with a vector. (This is a generalization since any linear function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is just a dot product with some vector.)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, $\alpha$ is a linear transformation that approximates the function $f$ well in a small region. I can only show you why the definition makes sense, but not tell the physical meaning.

You can find the following arguments in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

> In single variable case, we define the derivative at a point $x$ by $$L:=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ if such number $L$ exists. The number $L$ is called the derivative of $f$ at $x$. Equivalently, we have $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-L=0,$$ or $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh}{h}=0.$$
>   To generalise this expression to several variables, we put the norm sign in both the numerator and the denominator (so that division makes sense), and require that $L$ is a linear transformation. The function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if there exists a linear transformation $L$ such that
>   $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0.$$
>   The function $L$ is then the derivative of $f$ at $x$.