# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - (xy)^2}\, dx \, dy $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - (xy)^2}\, dx \, dy $$

Can someone provide a hint to tackle this problem? I only know how to do substitution and integration by parts for one variable. My difficulty so far is to express the term $ \dfrac{1}{1 - (xy)^2} $ in term of $ x $ treating $ y $ as a constant so that I can use substitution.

Comment: @Bye_World: it is faster to treat the integrand function as a geometric series and apply Fubini's theorem termwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{1-(xy)^2}=\iint_{(0,1)^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{2n}y^{2n}\,dx\,dy =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{8}}.$$

Comment: second equality is not clear

Comment: @ILoveMath: $\frac{1}{1-z^2}=1+z^2+z^4+\ldots$ even if $z=xy$.

Comment: got it now! nice +1

Comment: And by Fubini's theorem $$\iint_{(0,1)^2}x^{2n}y^{2n}\,dx dy = \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,dx \int_{0}^{1}y^{2n}\,dy = \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 6):

The section “Three times $\pi^2/6$” in
[Proofs from THE BOOK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3662442043)
by Aigner & Ziegler shows how to evaluate this integral using the completely non-obvious substitution
$$
x = \frac{\sin u}{\cos v}
,\qquad
y = \frac{\sin v}{\cos u}
,
$$
which magically turns the integral into
$$
\iint_E dudv
,
$$
where $E$ is the triangle with corners in $(u,v)=(0,0)$, $(\pi/2,0)$ and $(0,\pi/2)$.

This is a special case of the evaluation of $\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{nk} (2k+1)^{-n}$ in [a paper by Beukers, Calabi and Kolk](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kolk0101/Publications/calabi.pdf).

(See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/a-limit-and-a-coordinate-trigonometric-transformation-of-the-interior-points-of).)

Comment: That's an epic substitution.

Answer (score 4):

*A much less elegant solution.*

Consider
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{1 - (xy)^2} $$ and change variable $$xy=t\implies x=\frac ty\implies dx=\frac{dt}{y}$$ This make $$I=\frac 1y\int\frac{dt}{1 - t^2}= \frac {\tanh ^{-1}(t)}y=\frac {\tanh ^{-1}(xy)}y\implies \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1 - (xy)^2}=\frac {\tanh ^{-1}(y)}y$$ Now, using $$\tanh ^{-1}(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {y^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\implies \frac{\tanh ^{-1}(y)}y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {y^{2n}}{2n+1}$$ which makes $$J=\int \frac{\tanh ^{-1}(y)}y \,dy=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}$$ $$\int_0^1 \frac{\tanh ^{-1}(y)}y \,dy=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{8}$$